# C# Filtering a list using Linq requires ToList method to be called?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a list using Linq in c# as follows?

```
 // Returns a List<Person>
 var personList = getPersons();

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PersonName.Text))
     personList = personList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Joe"));
```

But I get error:

```
Cannot convert source type 'System.collections.Generic.Ienumerable<Mysite.Models.Person>' to target type 'System.collection.Generic.List<Mysite.Models.Person>
```

I have to do the following to fix i.e add ToList()

```
personList = personList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Joe")).ToList();
```

My question is why do I need to call ToList when the personList is already a list of type `List<Person>`?

Comment: Because `Where` doesn't return a list, it's basically just returning the query and not a collection. If you'd declare personList  as `IEnumerable<Person>` it would also compile.

Comment: @Tim the getPersons() method returns a List so cannot change it to IEnumerable. Would the same thing happen if i didnt use a lambda expression i.e. do something like `from p in personList where p.name == 'Joe'  select p`

Comment: List<T> implements IEnumerable<T> so you only need to replace var with IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and the `getPersons()` method returns a `List<Person>`. You can substitute a `List<T>` for an `IEnumerable<T>` but not the other way round.

As to how to fix it, it depends. If you want to use a method from `List<T>` on the collection of Person, then calling `.ToList()` is the correct way to handle it for example `.ForEach()`.

On the other hand if you don't need any methods / properties from `List<T>` then you can either declare the variable as `IEnumerable<Person> personList = getPersons();` or change the return type of `getPersons()`.

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

Comment: Even if you don't need methods from `List<T>` you should call `ToList` when you've applied all the filters. So not everytime you call `Where` but at the thend. Otherwise you would always execute the query when you touch the sequence.